# Пагинация страниц для парсера simple html dom

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom, пагинация

Нужно при парсинге страницы с помощью simple html dom, сделать пагинацию. То есть парсер в странице каталога собирает ссылки на товары, но собирает эти ссылки он с 1 страницы, как сделать чтобы он собирал и со второй (третьей,... пятой) тоже?

Нашел здесь же одно решение:

```
define('PAGE_COUNT', 250);
define('URL_PATTERN', "https://itp.ne.jp/genre_dir/9570/pg/[pnum]/?sr=1&ngr=1&num=20");

$urls = [];
for($pnum = 1; $pnum <= PAGE_COUNT; $pnum++){
    $urls[] = str_replace( '[pnum]', $pnum, URL_PATTERN);
}

print_r($urls);
```

Попробовал у себя сделать сделать так:

```
define('PAGE_COUNT', 2);
define('URL_PATTERN', "https://rozetka.com.ua/uslugi/c153670/page=[pnum]/");

$urls = [];
for($pnum = 1; $pnum <= PAGE_COUNT; $pnum++){
    $urls[] = str_replace( '[pnum]', $pnum, URL_PATTERN);


foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $html = curl_get($url);
    $dom = str_get_html($html);
    $services = $dom->find('.g-i-tile-i-box-desc');

foreach($services as $service){ 
    $a = $service->find('.g-i-tile-i-title a', 0);

echo $a->href . '<br>';
}

}

}
```

В итоге подгружается почему то только последнее значение - то есть вторая страница и с нее выгражаются нужные ссылки на товары, но соответственно с первой страницы ссылки не выгружаются.

Как сделать так чтобы выгружались ссылки и с первой и со второй страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум тут ошибка в коде, должно быть так (сначала заполнить весь массив url):

```
define('PAGE_COUNT', 2);
define('URL_PATTERN', "https://rozetka.com.ua/uslugi/c153670/page=[pnum]/");

$urls = [];
for($pnum = 1; $pnum <= PAGE_COUNT; $pnum++){
    $urls[] = str_replace( '[pnum]', $pnum, URL_PATTERN);
}

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $html = curl_get($url);
    $dom = str_get_html($html);
    $services = $dom->find('.g-i-tile-i-box-desc');

    foreach($services as $service){ 
        $a = $service->find('.g-i-tile-i-title a', 0);
        echo $a->href . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Ну и далее curl может тупо не забирает первую страницу если неподключен CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

с https://rozetka.com.ua/uslugi/c153670/page=1/ идет 301 редирект на https://rozetka.com.ua/uslugi/c153670/

Ну и если дело действительно в 301 редиректе вариант решения без ковыряния curl

```
define('PAGE_COUNT', 2);
define('URL_PATTERN', "https://rozetka.com.ua/uslugi/c153670/");

$urls = [];
for($pnum = 1; $pnum <= PAGE_COUNT; $pnum++){
    $urls[] = URL_PATTERN.($pnum==1 ? null : "page=$pnum/" );
}

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $html = curl_get($url);
    $dom = str_get_html($html);
    $services = $dom->find('.g-i-tile-i-box-desc');

    foreach($services as $service){ 
        $a = $service->find('.g-i-tile-i-title a', 0);
        echo $a->href . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!